Place labels on top of each stacked bar, and set font color in matplotlib
I have the following code (DF and graph):
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [['2005','A',10],['2006','A',15],['2007','A',10],
                       ['2005','B',15],['2006','B',70],['2007','B',10],
                       ['2005','C',75],['2006','C',15],['2007','C',80]
                      ]


df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=data, 
    columns=['year','type','count'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 7),facecolor = '#fdf1e6')
ax.set_facecolor('#fdf1e6')

ax = sns.histplot(df, x='year', 
                  hue='type', 
                  weights='count',
                  multiple='stack', 
                  shrink=0.9,
                  linewidth=3.5,
                  )

ax.get_legend().remove()

for c in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(c, fmt=lambda x: f'{x:.0%}' if x > 0 else '', label_type='center')

and the result is

I want to place each stack label on top of each stack (now is centered in each stack) and change font color to white.
Any idea?
Thanks!!!

ax.bar_label(c, fmt=lambda x: f'{x:.0%}' if x > 0 else '', color='w'). But the topmost labels are no longer visible (white on white).

@BigBen thanks! Yes, the problem is that matplotlib is placing labs on the botton of next stack, and not in the top of current stack,

Oh ... you mean just inside the bar, not on top the bar.

Removing label_type='center' (the default is 'edge'), using a negative value for padding, adding the color parameter, and using get_height to create the desired labels, something like:
for c in ax.containers:
    labs = [f'{r.get_height():.0%}' if r.get_height() > 0 else '' for r in c]
    ax.bar_label(c, labs, color='w', padding=-15)

Output:


The problem here es when you remove label_type='center', the labels shows the add up value from the first stack to top. The last one (the upper one) es 100%, when it should be, in the first column 12%

Try the edited version.

Great! What's the difference? And why the edited version solved the problem?

The bar_label docs specify what value is used for the labels depending on label_type, so "edge": the value displayed will be the position of that end-point. The edited version uses get_height to create the desired labels and override the default behavior.

And the sum up of the stacked bar?

Wouldn't that just be ax.bar_label(c, color='w', padding=-15)?
